# Don't know how to run a Python script

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a Python script, But I don't know where I should run it.

[image]

Comment: You are in the wrong directory.

Comment: You are in `Users/User`( not in `Programs/Python`)

Comment: So what should i type in command

Comment: `cd AppData\Local\Programs\Python` and then the `python` command. But why are you saving your script there?

Answer (score 0):

You are in wrong directory. First, change your directory with:

```
cd AppData\Local\Programs\Python
```

Then when you are in correct directory you can run:

```
python discordgenerator.py
```

[What is the cd command?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cd-cmd-command/)